# $(\bigoplus_{i \in I}\mathbb{Z})/H \cong \mathbb{Z} \Rightarrow \bigoplus_{i \in I} \mathbb{Z} \cong H \oplus \mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a free abelian group and $H \leq G$ such that $G/H \cong \mathbb{Z}$.
Does that imply that $G \cong H \oplus \mathbb{Z}$?

And if so, are there any similar statements, or generalizations of the above?
For example:

- Are there other conditions instead of $G/H \cong \mathbb{Z}$ that would guarantee that $G \cong H \oplus G/H$?
- Are there analogous statements for other types of groups instead of free abelian ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. An abelian group (module) $P$ for which every short exact sequence $0 \to H \to G \to P \to 0$ splits (which implies in particular that $G  \cong H \oplus P$) is called projective. All free modules are projective, so in particular, you can take $P$ to be any free abelian group, and $G$ and $H$ to be any abelian group whatsoever with $G/H \cong P$.

Comment: I guess you meant "which implies in particular that $G \cong H \oplus P$". Thanks!

Comment: Yes, sorry, that was true but stupid. Thanks for spotting it :). I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

If $G$ is an abelian group and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and the quotient $G/H$ is a free abelian group, then $G\cong H\oplus(G/H)$.  This applies in particular when $G/H$ is the free abelian group on one generator, namely $\mathbb Z$.